# Putting a title to a "mystery" movie

Tags: story-identification, movie

I vaguely remember watching a movie in primary school I watched it in p7 to be specific. So, I would have been 11, meaning the movie would have been pre-2000. possibly pre-1990 but I would say not pre-1980, basing this on the special effects.

This movie I feel had a sci-fi, mystery feel. The most notable part is the ending epilogue. The movie ends with a faded out scene while traversing through a dark room. Then the summary of a deep philosophical rhetorical question which has a "Meaning of life" feel. short but strong question, something like "What if?". I am sure that's the wrong question but I feel it was structured similarly.

The author H.G Wells comes to mind as I feel I can remember the teacher had a fascination with H.G Wells and aliens. I am pretty sure the movie had aliens in it. Similarly to *War of the Worlds* but older than the 2005 movie with Tom Cruise. In fact for the last two weeks I have been trying to identify this movie I keep convincing myself it had to have been *War of the Worlds* as it has a similar feel to the movie I am thinking about. I keep going round in circles as I have vague memory of the movie, the most memorable part is the ending of the movie fading out while traversing through a room almost like the camera is gliding through the room while text comes on the screen with the philosophical life rhetorical question. I remember taking a few minutes thinking about how profound the questions where. But for the life of me I can't remember or track similar questions that would spark a memory.

I have looked into multiple movies including H.G Wells and Stephen King adaptations including *Langoliers* and *The Time Machine*, unfortunately none of which fit the bill or had the ending scene.

I'm almost sure it would be anywhere from 1990 to 2003. The substitute teacher was very young and was very fond of the two movies and aliens and conspiracy theories surrounding those topics. From what I can remember, in terms of computer graphics, I am pushed to more recent movies to the time frame I watched it(1990-2003). I was 11 at the time in last year of primary school, so I was thinking that it must not have been an age restricted film, but since she was young, so that may not be the case.

I feel this has a vague similarity to the 2004 *[The Puppet Masters](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uq8-jf4F4O0)* in terms of movie special effects, acting, camera qualities, etc.

I am afraid I cannot remember any scenes from the movie apart from the final 10 seconds which I feel I can remember enough to draw a picture of. It was English and a full length movie with American actors, I believe, as I remember watching it then going for lunch and continuing to watch it after lunch and I am sure it was a movie as we had two movies and those were them unless the teacher tricked us into watching a TV show and making us believe it was a movie (quite possible but I am feeling it was not the case). I just wish I could remember enough of the story line or any details that would trigger me to remember the ultimatum type rhetorical question at the end, which was printed in text at the end of the movie like script writing similar to *Star Trek*. i feel it had a "If life must end then what next" sort of vibe.

That ending scene had the enemy (aliens) being defeated in a quiet, dark triumph, and then the end scene with the camera traversing through a dark hallway type environment with what I think is ivy leaves and vines wrapped around the furniture/walls and I remember on the left side of the scene, the back side of a living room type or rocking chair type seat with ivy and vines and during this scene, while we are travelling with the camera, this is when the writing is on the screen, not a lot but two sentences but it spans most of the scene, and then it fades to blackness and the credits begin.

Thank you to those helping me in the right direction, it definitely helps trigger the thoughts and emotions to what I was feeling when I was reading the writing at the end I am thinking for me now the best route is to try and aim to remember the writing as my memory of the movie is that insufficient that identifying the movie would be near impossible.

Comment: Can you describe any other scene in the film? Did the aliens do anything? Was it in English? Full-length or short? How large was the cast? Were they American? Foreign? Caucasian? Darker-skinned? What sort of special effects were there that made you think it was more recent? Were there CG graphics? If so, what sort of technology did they look like (vector, crude 3D with facets, smooth surfaces, post-production lighting, etc)?

Comment: You can find prompts at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info to help elicit further details. Any of that that you can answer will help.

Comment: Also, why did you tag *Paycheck*?

Comment: If the question at the end definitely was "what if?" Then I'd have suggested _[The Time Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Time_Machine_(2002_film))_ but it's a bit too recent.

Comment: Hi Ash, I should have mentioned I have looked into multiple movies including H.G Wells and Stephen King Adaptations unfortunately none of which fit the bill or had the ending scene.
Langoliers and The Time Machine and others I was unorganised and should have made a list while watching and researching the movies.

Comment: Yeah that was silly @FuzzyBoots I thought I would tag that so that if a correct answer came out of the search I would PP compensate whoever hit it on the nail.(which i will)

Comment: I'm almost sure it would be anywhere from 1990 to 2003. The substitute teacher was very young and had a very fond liking of the two movies and aliens and conspiracy theories surrounding those topics. +From what I can remember in terms of cg gfx I am pushed to more recent movies to the time frame I watched it(1990-2003).. +I was 11 at the time in last year of primary school so i was thinking that it must be age restricted but since she was young that may not be the case.

Comment: Im afraid I cannot remember any scenes from the movie apart from the final 10 seconds which I feel I can remember enough to draw a picture of. It was English and full length as I remember watching it going for lunch and continuing to watch it. I just wish I could remember enough of the storyline or any details that would trigger me to remember the ultimatum like rhetorical question at the end which was printed in text at the end of the movie like script writing similar to star trek. i feel it had a "If life must end then what next" sort of vibe.

Comment: I know this should probably be written off due to lack of information and I apologise for that.

Comment: Thank you to those helping me in the right direction, it definitely helps trigger the thoughts and emotions to what I was feeling when I was reading the writing at the end I am thinking for me now the best route is to try and aim to remember the writing as my memory of the movie is that insufficient that identifying the movie would be near impossible.

Comment: All i really have in regards memory is the enemy(aliens) becoming defeated a quiet, dark triumph and then the end scene with the camera traversing through a dark hallway type environment with what i think is ivy reeves and vines wrapped around the furniture/walls and i remember on the left side the backside of a living room type or rocking chair seat with ivy and vines and during this scene while we are travelling with the camera this is when the writing is on the screen not a lot two sentences but it spans most of the scene and then it fades to blackness and the credits begin.This is accurate

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uq8-jf4F4O0 this movie to me is a close similarity to the CG gfx, acting and camera qualities to the movie i have in mind. in saying this its not a strong memory so its a vague similarity if any of that makes sense sorry its late im just in the house.

Comment: Im pretty sure it would have been american actors.

Comment: :) I would advise editing these details into your question.

Comment: So its a movie with aliens being defeated but in a way that isn’t entirely triumphant which closes on a rocking chair covered in ivy with a slow fade to black over a quote questioning what we would really do. That’s not a lot to go on.

Comment: @Broklynite I know pal not much info of the movie scenes or storylines. I was just hoping someone would have memory of any similar movies.

Comment: Did you watch this in 1 day or over a couple of days? If it was one class period, that means it's most likely a TV series episode running slightly under an hour. This combined with the epilogue at the end makes it sound like an Outer Limits episode from the 90s series.

Comment: You may want to expand a bit more on the teacher and the movies. From what you've said, it sounds like the teacher may have shown the movies multiple times - is that correct, or did she simply say these were her favorite movies? Were the two movies related (for instance, one a sequel to another). As noted, could it have been a two-part story from a TV show? Was there a connection between the movie(s) and what you were studying in class, or were they just for fun?